# Error en las rutas de angular modo producción

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy empezando con angular pero tengo un problema al hacer que en modo me producción me arroje errores por ejemplo si estoy en componente noticias y escribo una url errónea debería mandarme un 404(mi propio componente 404 funcionaba en localhost) pero no es así me redirecciona a error 404 del hosting  ¿qué puede estar mal

[image: estas son mis rutas]

[image: error que me arroja el servidor]